# "Good" way how to update state (from its previous value) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, readability, state-management

#### From react doc

From the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) I could see handling of on-off button changes by arrow function like:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
  }));
}
```

Important thing in here (for me) is, that the **new state value is derived from its previous state value**.
If I am right, the behaviour is the same as (without arrow function):

```
handleClick() {     
    this.setState(function (prevState){
      return {isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn}
    });
}
```

or even without function at all:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({isToggleOn: this.state.isToggleOn ? 
    false : true});
}
```

**1) Are there any differences in these except the code-style?**
All approaches seems to work for me and I could not find any difference (except readability).

**2) I thought, this.setState is only "setter", how the "prevState" can be passed into that function?**

**3) Is it mistake to write the code like this (3th approach)?** I became from "old-school" and I did not develop for more than 5 years, now I am returning to dev slowly. The first one example is hardly understandable for me (because of arrow functions and anonymous function), second one is clearer a little bit but the last one is the most self-explaining to me.

---

#### Real life example

"Real learn (life)" example what I am struggling right now:
As I am learning, I am trying to write my own calculator (starting with only basic functionality). Because of bad "design" (I found out it will be much better to use some array, fields, lists instead of only "variableA, variableB", but never the less..).
My app structure is:

- Calculator

  - ResultHeader

    - Input (for result)
    - Input (for printing the equation)
  - CalcButton (0)

    - Button
  - ...
  - CalcButton (X)

    - Button

CalcButton contains props for its value ([0...9], x, /, +, -, C, ...) and event handlers (numberClick, operatorClick). When number button is pressed, it lifts its state to Calculator, which adds the number to valueA or valueB, depends on the state of "isFirst". operatorClick contains switch for its own functionality and if x, /, +, - was pressed, it sets isFirst on false and user can continue with second number (valueB). Now the code of this handler:

```
onNumberClick(e) {
    function appendA() {
        return {valueA: this.state.valueA + e};
    }

    function appendB() {
        return {valueB: this.state.valueB + e};
    }

    this.setState(this.state.isFirst ? appendA : appendB);

    /*
    if(this.state.isFirst) { 
        this.setState({valueA: this.state.valueA + e});
    } else {
        this.setState({valueB: this.state.valueB + e});
    }
    */
}
```

Commented code is basically the same as 3th example, even the uncommented variant, only with some "readability" improvements. Last 2 days I am stuck if there is any possibility to use some anonymous arrow function so I do not need to duplicate the code (one time for valueA, one time for valueB). Because of javascript and its lack of object referencing, the only solution I was able to figure was to pass the argument via string ("valueA" || "valueB") but I think it is not nice solution. The important thing in here is (as in the example at the top), the **new state value is derived from its previous value** (that is why I am still thinking about using arrow anonymous function).

Can somebody show me some examples how to achieve that? Is arrow function necessary in here (is it even possible to do this by arrow function?) or is this "code" just fine and I am finding problems where there are none?

Comment: Passing the setter a function is the only way to guarantee that you dont get a stale value.

Comment: why don't you use `useEffect` hooks? and `set` the value of your `state` by using `setYourState`. 
Easy!! isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React batches state updates. If the state is updated with `setState` in one section of the code, and then some other part of the code *synchronously* calls `setState` again, the prior value set may not be reflected in `this.state` yet. For example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ foo: 'foo' });
    console.log('after setting state, this.state.foo is:', this.state.foo);
    // so, further logic that depends on this.state.foo being 'foo' will fail
  }
  render() {
    return 'My App';
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

In other words, you can't reliably do

```
this.setState({ someProp: someVal });
// refer to this.state.someProp here
// because it may well refer to the state before it was updated
// not the new state which contains someVal
```

If, like in your particular situation, you do not have multiple synchronous state updates - then there is no problem, because the state will update almost immediately after a click, and before another click can be processed. So, your

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({isToggleOn: this.state.isToggleOn ? 
    false : true});
}
```

is safe - or, more concisely:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn });
}
```

as long as you don't do something *else* immediately before or after `handleClick` that depends on or changes `this.state.isToggleOn`.

You only need the functional version, eg

```
handleClick() {     
    this.setState(function (prevState){
      return {isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn}
    });
}
```

if the state may have just been set (synchronously) by code above, before a re-render. See the first snippet in this answer for an example - in such a situation, if you wanted to call `this.setState` again, and use the value for `this.state.foo` that was just set, you'd want to use the callback form.

> I thought, this.setState is only "setter", how the "prevState" can be passed into that function?

React internals keep track of the current value of the state when `setState` is called, and they pass the updated value into the callback, despite the fact that the component's `this.state` may not have been updated yet.

> Is it mistake to write the code like this (3th approach)?

Not at all, as long as you're aware of the limitation. (If your `setState` does not depend on state values that have *just been set* by a call to `this.setState` earlier, your third approach is just fine.)

Just for a contrived example, if your app had a button that incremented a counter, and another button that increases a state value by the amount of the counter, one option would be to use the callback version in combination with multiple calls to `setState`:

```
updateSum() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
    this.incrementByOne();
  }
}
incrementByOne() {
  this.setState(prev => ({ sum: prev.sum + 1 }));
}
```

The above `incrementByOne`, since it's being called multiple times, would only work if it uses the callback version. If it did

```
this.setState({ sum: this.state.sum + 1 });
```

it would not function properly, since `this.state.sum` would not be updated from the previous synchronous calls to `incrementByOne`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @CertainPerformance for your amazing comment! But what about:

        if(this.state.isFirst) { 
            this.setState({
                valueA: this.state.valueA + e
            },
            () => console.log(this.state.valueA),
            );
        } else {
            this.setState({
                valueB: this.state.valueB + e
            },
            () => console.log(this.state.valueB),
            );
        }

This is, if I am right, the same callback, right?

Comment: Only one that I am not sure if I understand right is the callback with the arrow function. Does it mean, that "prevState" is callback for the setState? First iteration (init), the callback is {} (or undefined?) and in that case it has no ".isToggleOn" value, how is it possible it works after init?

Comment: That's a bit different. You can choose none, either, or both of: (1) Pass a callback as the first argument to `setState`. The first argument provided will be the most updated state, which may not be reflected in `this.state` yet. Eg `this.setState(prevState => { doStuffWithPrevState }`. (2) Then there's the *second* argument, an optional callback, that runs after the state update is complete, which I did not mention in the answer. `this.setState({ prop: 'newVal' }, () => console.log('state update finished'))`

Comment: First iteration, the argument to the callback will be the current state - equivalent to `this.state`. On further calls, the argument will be the most updated state (kept track by React internals), but not reflected in `this.state` yet.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explanation. You rocks! Really thank you very much, I really appreciate people with the ability to explain me something in such a great way.