# updating state object property - date, based on previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to increment date with each button click (next day each click). How to update object state property and increment date value, properly???

```js
const {useState} = React;

const DateComponent = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState({
    currDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
    active: true
  });

  const nextDate = () => {
    setDate({
      ...date,
      currDate: date.currDate.setDate(date.currDate.getDate() + 1)
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{date.currDate}</span>
      <button onClick={nextDate}>Next Day</button>
    </div>
  );
}




ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <DateComponent />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: currDate is a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Good" way how to update state (from its previous value) in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081468/good-way-how-to-update-state-from-its-previous-value-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `currDate` state as a `Date` object and make it a string during component rendering to view it as follows.

Create a temporary Date object `tempDate` to clone the current date and then do the update.

```
const DateComponent = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState({
    currDate: new Date(),
    active: true,
  });

  const nextDate = () => {
    setDate(currentData => {
      const tempDate = new Date(currentData.currDate.getTime());
      tempDate.setDate(currentData.currDate.getDate() + 1);

      return {
        ...currentData,
        currDate: tempDate,
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{date.currDate.toLocaleDateString()}</span>
      <button onClick={nextDate}>Next Day</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it returns  "date.currDate.toLocaleDateString is not a function"

Comment: Sorry for the error I made. Please check the updated answer @Adrian

Comment: Btw, why do we need to create a temp obj and then clone?

Comment: In react we shouldn't directly change the state object. It should only be changed through `setState` function. That's why I just cloned it to the temp obj and then do the change to it before updating the state.

Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it, its using the preview object for that state when you use `setDate` you can access to that value in the function, this is how you can use it

```
const nextDate = () => {
  setDate(prev => {
    const newDate = new Date(prev.currDate)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1)
    return {
      ...prev,
      currDate: newDate.toLocaleDateString(),
    };
  });
};
```